# Unable to create a new column using a function in R

Tags: r, function

I'm trying to create a new column within a function.  Basically, I want to use a function to create a new field, based on an old field (using string searching).  Having no luck:

```
old_field <- c("September 2012", "September 2012")
case_id <- c("1","1")
my_df <- data.frame(case_id, old_field)

old_date_to_new_date <- function(df, new_date, old_date) {
     
     df[[new_date]][grepl('Sep', old_date, ignore.case = TRUE)] <- '09-01' #if 'sep' found in old date field, put "09-01" in new date field. 
     df[[new_date]][grepl('2012', old_date, ignore.case = TRUE)] <- paste('2012-',new_date,sep='')# add year to new date field
    }
    
    old_date_to_new_date (my_df,"new_field","old_field")
```

The function runs just fine, but fails to add the new column to the dataframe.  I've tested this and I can't even modify anything within the dataframe using the function.  Code works fine outside of the function and does what expected.  I've tried adding a `return(df)` statement within the function but still no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to return the data along with get the value of the column using `[[`

```
old_date_to_new_date <- function(df, new_date, old_date) {
     i1 <- grepl('Sep', df[[old_date]], ignore.case = TRUE)
     i2 <- grepl('2012', df[[old_date]], ignore.case = TRUE)
     df[[new_date]][i1] <- '09-01' #if 'sep' found in old date field, put "09-01" in new date field. 
     df[[new_date]][i2] <- paste('2012-',df[[new_date]][i2],sep='')# add year to new date field
     df
    }
    

old_date_to_new_date (my_df,"new_field","old_field")
#   case_id      old_field  new_field
#1       1 September 2012 2012-09-01
#2       1 September 2012 2012-09-01
```

NOTE: If we need to update the original object, assign the output back to the original object

```
my_df <- old_date_to_new_date (my_df,"new_field","old_field")
```

Comment: hm, still not working.  I can print the value of the old_date (which already exists) in the function, but cannot modify or add column.

Comment: @DiamondJoe12 Sorry, you need the `grepl` on the lhs and rhs

Comment: @DiamondJoe12 please check the update.  If that doesn't work, can you please update your post with a small reproducible example using `dput`

Comment: shoot, it says function(df, new_date, old_date) { : 
  invalid (NULL) left side of assignment

Comment: @DiamondJoe12 would you be able to show a small example for testing

Comment: see updated question - there's an example df I built that is a replication of the data i'm working with, basically.  You will see that the function fails to add the column.

Comment: @DiamondJoe12 it is creating the column based on the data you showed

Comment: @DiamondJoe12 i updated the post with the output I am getting

Comment: @DiamondJoe12 unlike in python or some other langauges, `R` functions generally doesn't have side effects i.e. it won't change the original object unless you are doing `:=` with data.table